# FFT on a specific part of an image [python]

Tags: fft, python, interference

I'm currently working on a project where I have to analyse an interferogram. Instead of doing an FFT on the whole image I'd like to focus only on a small part of it (one fringe) is it possible to define a vector along which I want my FFT to be "done" ? There's also the option where I crop my interferogram but this is way less satisfying.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are, in essence, cropping the thing no matter what.  Why is literally cropping the interferogram less satisfying?  Because of the extra computation involved, because you want a 1D vector, or what?  Please _edit your question_ to include this information.

Comment: No I'm not cropping no matter what. Actually I'd like to keep the whole image but only apply a Fourier transform on a small part of it. My teacher said that he found a way to do it on Matlab using a vector and applying a FFT along it.